# Using Reselect in mapState to add together selector values

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

Feel like I'm missing something simple here.

If I have the following selectors (see code). Using Reselect how can I combine them together to make a new selector? I'm looking to do something like this...

```
export const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    //SELECTORS!
    sub1: selector(state, 'sub1') || 0,
    sub2: selector(state, 'sub2') || 0,
    totalSelector: createSelector(sub1, sub2, (sub1, sub2) => ({total: sub1 + sub2}))
  };
};
```

Does this need to be done outside of mapState? Currently sub1 and sub2 in 6th line are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they need to be defined before an object is created, like:

```
export const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
  const sub1 = selector(state, 'sub1') || 0;
  const sub2 = selector(state, 'sub2') || 0;
  return {
    //SELECTORS!
    sub1,
    sub2,
    totalSelector: createSelector(sub1, sub2, (sub1, sub2) => ({total: sub1 + sub2}))
  };
};
```

The problem is that in your `mapState` you pass undefined to `createSelector` function because `sub1` and `sub2` is not yet created. You need to create them before the returned object is constructed.